# How to navigate properly in SplitScreen

Tags: flutter, dart, ipad

I am working on the `iPad` and I have set up the screen to be `SplitScreens`. Thus I have two `Navigators` side by side. However, when I push a new `Screen` from the second Navigator I get a weird animation where the second screen (right) overlaps the first screen (left).

Please look at this video that explains it very good:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuYNA.jpg

```
SplitView(
  menu: Navigator(
    key: firstSplitNavigatorKey,
    onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            const KursplanungScreen(title: 'Demo App'),
      );
    },
  ),
  content: Navigator(
    key: secondSplitNavigatorKey,
    onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Text(
                    "Herzlich Willkommen!"))),
      );
    },
  ),
  menuWidth: 300,
),
```

Then somewhere in the second screen i call this:

```dart
TextButton(
  onPressed: () => secondSplitNavigatorKey.currentState!.push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => const CourseOverviewScreen(),
      ),
    ),
  child: const Text("Bearbeiten"),
),
```

How can I avoid that third weird animation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Navigator object to handle the right side pages.Use a Navigator object as widget father of the right side and handle the stack of pages to navigate only in this side. The default Navigator will change the entire page and will create a whole new one.
The left side, don't need to have a Navigator, only handle it using Widgets states(StatefullWidget or something like that).

```
SplitView(
    menu: MenuSideBar(
      onChangeSection: (Widget section) {
      setState((){
        pages.last=section;
      });
    }),
    content: Navigator(
      pages: pages,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: I need to also push from the left side separately that's why I am using two Navigators

Comment: There are many things you could do. The weird animation is due to the MaterialPageRouter, the MaterialPageRouter have this implicit animation. The faster way to fix that is using PageRouterBuilder instead MaterialPageRouter and set anmationDuration on 0.  `PageRouteBuilder(
                      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
                        return const Page2();
                      },
                      transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                      reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero,
                    )`

Comment: That's works. But when I for example use Dismissable (right side of the screen) for a Listview to delete items it still goes other the left side of the screen.

Comment: The same problem, the animation move the the object to le left side of the screen. Yo need to remove the animation or change it.

Comment: and how can I delete the animation of a `Dismissable`?